# File I/O operations - strange character entry?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, c-strings

I am using the `str.erase()` function in the following program to erase certain part of output. But at the last I am getting a strange output like this `����`.

The content of my file is `Current name of the file = ABCD-1234`

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
//std::ifstream;

int main ()
{
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("/home/highlander141/NetBeansProjects/erase_remove/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/abc.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( !myfile.eof() ) //myfile.good()
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
        //line = myfile.get();
        //if(!myfile.eof())
      cout << line <<endl;
      std::string str (line); 
      str.erase (str.begin()+0, str.end()-9);
      std::cout << str << endl;

    }
      myfile.close();
      //remove("/home/highlander141/NetBeansProjects/erase_remove/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/abc.txt");
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

return 0;
}
```

And output of my program is

```
Current name of the file = ABCD-1234
ABCD-1234

����

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: Could you show the real code? `line` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: @JesseGood Please check the modified code now...

Comment: You don't check the return value from `getline`, and using `eof` that way is incorrect.  You also don't check if the line is long enough for `str.end() -9` to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for `eof()` before reading the input.  Modify the loop as follows:

```
while ( 1 )
{
    getline (myfile,line);
    if ( myfile.eof() )
        break;

    // Rest of the loop
}
```

Comment: Why not `while(getline (myfile,line))`?  Checking for `eof` is rarely the right way to handle things.